# PJSIP library not found at Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, pjsip, pjsua2

I am new in iOS. I am trying to build an app with PJSIP. I have build library for all architecture and include header file to project and also add search path:[header and library search path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8FMr.png)

project directory [directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKmYR.png)

but I found error like this [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO1mc.png)

Where I am wrong ?

Comment: Now, PJSIP added example application, you can try and check what's wrong with your configs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by adding the Bridge_Header.h file. And also add the directory by drag and drop.